# When deleting and creating performance counters in a service it can hang the service

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

In a app i have written we delete and recreate the performance counters as the app spins up.

When running this from a console the application deletes and recreates the counters and the counter category fine.

When we run from a service, the app deletes the counter category as expected but when creating the new category it hangs until the service times out

```
     if (PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(CATEGORY_NAME))
     {
        PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete(CATEGORY_NAME);
     }
```

Works ok but then hangs in this method

```
      private PerformanceCounterCategory RecreateTheCategory()
  {
     PerformanceCounterCategory category = null;
     if (!PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(CATEGORY_NAME))
     {
        category = PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(CATEGORY_NAME, CATEGORY_HELP,
                                                     PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance,
                                                     counterCreationDataCollection);
     }
     return category;
  }
```

on the .Exists line. I expect this is something to do with permissions but as in production we have to run the service as Local System I really need to fix it in code without elevating the user account

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, i needed to do my IOC build up in the OnStart() method and no the constructor

Comment: Mark your comment as the accepted answer then so we know not to come looking to try to answer it.